# gridviewitem from textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, windows-8

now I am creating a gridview and I want to fill this grid view with String items generated from textbox , but with my own template for the GridviewItem , how I bind textblock in the gridviewitem template with the string added from the textbox

```
private void onTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Taglist.Items.Add(tagBox.Text);         
    tagBox.Text = "";
}
```

this is the Xaml :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="listitemTemplate">
        <Grid Height="164" Width="651">
            <Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/new design/tags.PNG"/>
            </Grid.Background>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Text}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="136,49,0,0" Height="69" Width="406" FontSize="48"   />
        </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I found my mistake , I should write in the binding , `Text = "{Binding}"`  that's it

the correct xaml is :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="listitemTemplate"> 
    <Grid Height="164" Width="651"> 
        <Grid.Background> 
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/new design/tags.PNG"/> 
        </Grid.Background> 
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="136,49,0,0" Height="69" Width="406" FontSize="48" /> 
    </Grid> 
</DataTemplate>
```